# Rollover will not swap

Tags: javascript

Hey im having trouble with my javascript rollover.  The image does not change.  Ive had a look at some tutorials and i cant see where im going wrong.

Here is my code:

Home.xhtml

```
 <img src="images/Weights.png" width="900" height="300" border="0" alt="Gym Equipment" name="gym"
     onMouseOver="swapImage('gym','treadmill');" onmouseout="swapImage('gym','weights');"/>
```

newjs.js

```
// Pre load images for rollover
if (document.images) 
{
    treadmill = new Image
    weights = new Image

    treadmill.src = "images/Treadmill.png"
    weights.src = "images/Weights.png"
}


function swapImage(thisImage,newImage) 
{
    if (document.images) 
        {
        document[thisImage].src = eval(newImage + ".src")
    }
}
```

How i tell the app where the js is:

Comment: newImage is a parameter for the function. Then newImage is goin to bewhat ever i tell it so in this case weights and gym.

Answer (score 1):

```
document[thisImage].src = eval(newImage + ".src")
```

should be

```
document[thisImage].src = eval(newImage ).src
```

Comment: aha got the error , you have to wait for images to load , thats why your codedoesnt work , maybe you have kinda large sized images.

Comment: image sizes are 600X900px both of them :(  even in your demonstration the rollover didnt work is this a browser problem ???

Answer (score 1):

Please avoid using `eval()` as it is generally the slowest way to evaluate code and there are some circumstances where it introduces security risks depending upon where the data comes from that you're calling eval on.

You should be able to make this work:

HTML:

```
<img src="images/Weights.png" width="900" height="300" border="0" alt="Gym Equipment" name="gym"
 onMouseOver="swapImage(this,'treadmill');" onmouseout="swapImage(this,'weights');"/>
```

Javascript:

```
// Pre load images for rollover
window.treadmill = new Image();
window.weights = new Image();

treadmill.src = "images/Treadmill.png"
weights.src = "images/Weights.png"

// this function must be defined globally 
//   (e.g. not defined inside any other function)
function swapImage(thisImage,newImageName) {
    thisImage.src = window[newImageName].src;
}
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/cv8tT/

Changes I made:

1. Removed the use of `eval()` and use `window[name]` to access global variables.
2. Changed the way `swapImage()` is called in the HTML to pass `this` so you can directly access the desired image.
3. Remove the `if (document.images)` checks since it is no longer used by the code.

FYI, all this could be done with CSS and background images with no javascript at all.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but still no joy :(

Comment: @BeckyOBrien - then you have some other issue that you haven't disclosed.  Is `swapImage()` defined as a global function?  Do you see any browser errors?  Also, are you aware that you could do all this with CSS and no javascript?

Comment: No browser errors on either the home.xhtml or the newjs.js.  Yes i know i could do it in css but i need to be able to show some sort of use for javascript.

Comment: @BeckyOBrien - I've fixed it up so it works now.  Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/cv8tT/

Comment: @BeckyOBrien - see the list of changes in my answer.

Comment: it is weird that his original code works on my browser with local images !!

Comment: @BeckyOBrien - you will have to show us your actual app because something else you are doing is making it not work.  Do you see an errors in the browser error console?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a slightly different approach by taking the mouseover and mouseout attributes out of your image tag. This will help keep your code more maintainable.

[I made a DEMO jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/JY5AP/)

- Note that I am using 3 images from Flickr, the default, one on mouseover, and one on mouseout. I hope this helps.

** Also note that the img tag now has an ID which is referenced in the bindings.

```
// Pre Load Images
var img1 = new Image();
var img2 = new Image();

img1.src = "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3230/2953035318_b54956e7df_q.jpg";
img2.src = "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3026/2992860864_aa9e8b0818_q.jpg";

// Event binding function
var bindEvent = function (el, eventName, eventHandler) {
    if (el.addEventListener != null) {
        return el.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler, false);
    } else if (el.attachEvent != null) {
        return el.attachEvent('on' + eventName, eventHandler);
    }
}

// Mouseover binding
bindEvent(document.getElementById('surfer'), "mouseover", function (e) {
    this.setAttribute("src", img1.src);
});

// Mouseout Binding
bindEvent(document.getElementById('surfer'), "mouseout", function (e) {
    this.setAttribute("src", img2.src);
});
```